# Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory - Magento 2 module

Tags: database, magento2

I have developed a module that has worked well previously on Magento 2. I now find the following error when I enable the module with composer:

```
Please upgrade your database: Run "bin/magento setup:upgrade" from the Magento root directory. 
The following modules are outdated:
Creare_Example schema: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
Creare_Example data: current version - none, required version - 2.0.0
```

I have ran the database upgrade command as requested, but I then get this error:

[image]

The extension has a simple data install script which I imagine has already ran, but now I can't get any further. Has anybody else encountered this problem?

I'm running Magento 2 on the following Vagrant Box: https://github.com/rgranadino/mage2_vagrant

Comment: Try to kill the mysql and start it.

Comment: I sometime have this messages when try to run command from host machine and not form VM...

Comment: Does your module.xml include `setup_version`? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/create_module.html

Comment: I have restarted the server and have checked that my module does have a setup version.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute that command into the vagrant box via SSH:

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ cd [magento-path]
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
```